# Great challenge - convert XML structure to php code

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, knockoutjs

I'm working in a project which i need convert the **minicart** `xml` structure to a `php` code.

I made all this.
But i don't know why he does't call or read my templates html.

I compared the `json` structure generated by my `php` code with that of `xml` and this equals.

**Part of struture XML**

http://prntscr.com/de58kk

**Part of my PHP code**

http://prntscr.com/de5916

The components are ok, the only one which does not work is the templates.

When i test which the xml and verify the Network tab on Chrome.
The `content.html` is loaded.

But when i test with my php code not load.

`Json` code renderized on the end of document.

Thanks.

```
"Magento_Ui/js/core/app":{  
   "components":{  
      "minicart_content":{  
         "children":{  
            "subtotal.container":{  
               "children":{  
                  "subtotal":{  
                     "children":{  
                        "subtotal.totals":{  
                           "config":{  
                              "display_cart_subtotal_incl_tax":0,
                              "display_cart_subtotal_excl_tax":1,
                              "template":"Magento_Tax\/checkout\/minicart\/subtotal\/totals"
                           },
                           "component":"Magento_Tax\/js\/view\/checkout\/minicart\/subtotal\/totals",
                           "children":{  
                              "subtotal.totals.msrp":{  
                                 "component":"Magento_Msrp\/js\/view\/checkout\/minicart\/subtotal\/totals",
                                 "config":{  
                                    "displayArea":"minicart-subtotal-hidden",
                                    "template":"Magento_Msrp\/checkout\/minicart\/subtotal\/totals"
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "component":"uiComponent",
                     "config":{  
                        "template":"Magento_Checkout\/minicart\/subtotal"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "component":"uiComponent",
               "config":{  
                  "displayArea":"subtotalContainer"
               }
            },
            "item.renderer":{  
               "component":"uiComponent",
               "config":{  
                  "displayArea":"defaultRenderer",
                  "template":"Magento_Checkout\/minicart\/item\/default"
               },
               "children":{  
                  "item.image":{  
                     "component":"Magento_Catalog\/js\/view\/image",
                     "config":{  
                        "template":"Magento_Catalog\/product\/image",
                        "displayArea":"itemImage"
                     }
                  },
                  "checkout.cart.item.price.sidebar":{  
                     "component":"uiComponent",
                     "config":{  
                        "template":"Magento_Checkout\/minicart\/item\/price",
                        "displayArea":"priceSidebar"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "extra_info":{  
               "component":"uiComponent",
               "config":{  
                  "displayArea":"extraInfo"
               }
            },
            "promotion":{  
               "component":"uiComponent",
               "config":{  
                  "displayArea":"promotion"
               }
            }
         },
         "config":{  
            "itemRenderer":{  
               "default":"defaultRenderer",
               "simple":"defaultRenderer",
               "virtual":"defaultRenderer"
            },
            "template":"Magento_Checkout\/minicart\/content"
         },
         "component":"Magento_Checkout\/js\/view\/minicart"
      }
   },
   "types":[  

   ]
}
},
```